"Cannot disable <system app> no root permission" when disabling some system packages on vivo X100
When disabling the system apps on vivo X100, some failed with the following error:

Exception occurred while executing 'disable-user':
java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot disable com.bbk.theme no root permission

127|V2308:/ $ pm disable-user --user 0 com.bbk.theme

Exception occurred while executing 'disable-user':
java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot disable com.bbk.theme no root permission
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.setEnabledSettingInternalLocked(PackageManagerService.java:4568)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.setEnabledSettings(PackageManagerService.java:4472)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.-$$Nest$msetEnabledSettings(PackageManagerService.java:0)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.setApplicationEnabledSetting(PackageManagerService.java:6357)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runSetEnabledSetting(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2523)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:292)
        at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:7005)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:1134)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:954)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:5024)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:6989)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1410)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1341)


V2308:/ $ pm disable-user --user 0 com.vivo.imanager

Exception occurred while executing 'disable-user':
java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot disable com.vivo.imanager no root permission
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.setEnabledSettingInternalLocked(PackageManagerService.java:4568)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.setEnabledSettings(PackageManagerService.java:4472)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.-$$Nest$msetEnabledSettings(PackageManagerService.java:0)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.setApplicationEnabledSetting(PackageManagerService.java:6357)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runSetEnabledSetting(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:2523)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:292)
        at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
        at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:7005)
        at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:1134)
        at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:954)
        at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:5024)
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService$IPackageManagerImpl.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:6989)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1410)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1341)


Why do you think it should be possible to disable these packages? A lot of are required by the system which you would never expect. Removing such packages may prevent your system from booting.
